# Does it sound good

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

"I am better growing up than you".

I am little bit confused hearing this sentence in the context of someone cultural environment for growing up is better than someone other

Does it sounds good grammatically.

Comment: Need more context. It does not make sense. What sort of "better" are you using?

Comment: Suppose someone's cultural environment for growing up better than someone else.in this context does sentence sounds good grammatically

Answer (score 3):

I don't think "I am better growing up than you" makes sense.

"I had it better growing up than you." means a better cultural/financial/emotional/physical environment.

"I was a better student/swimmer growing up than you." or "I was better at school/swimming growing up than you." means that was true when we were kids (even if not of the same generation), but not necessarily now (one of you could still be a kid) or when both were adults.

To really stretch it, "I am better at growing up than you." could mean that I am maturing faster or better (physically - e.g., taller; emotionally - e.g., more stable or faster to being stable, or in habits/abilities/skills) than you but this is awkward and I would not use it.

Comment: Yes you are correct.one more thing how an adjective can modify a verb

Comment: sorry Deep, I don't understand your question..  Is it a new/general question? (If so, ask a new question).  If it is related to this question, perhaps modify your original question so that we can understand it.

Comment: No michael .Iam saying you are correct just by saying "an adjective can not qualify a verb".

Comment: okay, i understand